# process value of an attribute of an object without changing it in python

Tags: python, attributes, copy

Hello I am struggling with a Problem in my Python code.

My problem is the following: I want to copy the value of an attribute of an object.
I create the object agent, then in the function train_agent() I copy the value of the attribute state_vec to the variable last_state_vec. The Problem now is, when I change last_state_vec I automatically also change the attribute state_vec of agent `state_vec = np.array(0,0,10,0,0)`. How can I only copy the value of state_vec, so that it doesn't get changed in this case. I want state_vec to stay the zero vector.
Here's some of my code:

```css
class DQN():
  def __init__(self)
  self.state_vec = np.zeros(5)
 
 
agent = DQN()

def train_agent(agent): 
  last_state_vec = agent.state_vec
  last_state_vec[2] = 10
  
  return 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside train_agent() function you can set last_state_vec to agent.state_vec.copy().

Currently you are initializing the variable last_state_vec  with the reference of agent.state_vec.

So By replacing it with agent.state_vec.copy() should do the trick !

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a shallow copy you can use np.copy, like so:

`last_state_vec = agent.state_vec.copy()`

That should work in this case since there are only integers in there.

In the event that you are storing *objects* in the state_vec you will need to use deepcopy, like so:

`last_state_vec = copy.deepcopy(agent.state_vec)`

You'll need to import `copy` for this.

The NumPy documentation gives examples of both types of copying.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html